# node.js For i in files render item

Tags: node.js, express

I want to repeat some items in my template (twig) on different places, where each repeated item responds to file names in different directories, so first I need an array with filenames.
I don't know how to affect outer scope from function. This will not work:

```
var files_list = {'json': [], 'js': []}
fs.readdir('./public/json', function(err, items) {
        if (err) throw err;
       files_list.json = items;
    });
res.render('index', { js: files_list.js, jsons: files_list.json });
```

This works, but how to render it again to get something from another directory.

```
fs.readdir('./public/json', function(err, items) {
            if (err) throw err;
           res.render('index', { jsons: items });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a var that you does't have synchronously at hand; So you should treat it the asynchronous way:

Use a **callback** function:

```
var getFiles = function(dir, cb) {
  fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
    if (err) cb(err, null);
    cb(null, files);
  });
};
```

Usage:

```
getFiles('./public/json', function(err, files) {
  if (err) throw err;
  res.render('index', { jsons: files });
});
```

---

Or a **promise**:

```
var getFiles = function(dir) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(files);
    });  
  });
};
```

Usage:

```
getFiles('./public/json')
  .then(function(files) {
    res.render('index', { jsons: files });
  }, function(err) {
    throw err;
  });
```